# jQuery- counting amount of rows and adding attribute - condition not met

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to count the amount of rows using the "offset().top" value of each of the articles on the page. The first two conditions are met but the last one to determine the next row is never met, I can

```
var datarow = 1;
var rowNum = 0;
    if(prev.length == 0){
        datarow = 1;
        $this.attr("data-row", datarow);
    }
    else if(prev.length > 0 && $this.offset().top == prev.offset().top){
        $this.attr("data-row", datarow);
    }
    else if(prev.length > 0 && $this.offset().top != prev.offset().top){ // THIS CONDITION IS NEVER MET
        rowNum++;
        $this.attr("data-row", datarow + rowNum);
    }
    console.log("rowNum is:" + rowNum);
```

I'm rather new to using jQuery so please pardon any novice mistakes.
Here is a fiddle to show you what I'm trying to accomplish and so that the code above has more context. https://jsfiddle.net/JackofD/a598Lp0c/1/
and the fullscreen result https://jsfiddle.net/JackofD/a598Lp0c/1/embedded/result/

Any help is well appreciated
Thanks in advance

P.S I'm trying the add the attribute data-row to each article, the ones in the next row should have an incremented data-row attribute. I get the first row to work, the items on the next row(basically floated below) don't ever get and incremented data-row(eg, data-row="2").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works. I have rewritten the script in a slightly diff. way. Check only the script part of below code.

And this covers all possible counts and positioning that you might need.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .contentWrapper{
        width: 98%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 1% auto;
        padding: 1%;
        outline: 1px solid #999;
        float: left;
    }

        .promotionWrapper{
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            outline: 1px dotted #666;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 1%;
            margin-bottom: .5%;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .result{
            background: #999;
            width: 90%;
            height: auto;
            margin: .5% auto;
            color: #fff;
            padding: .5%;
        }


.clearfloat{
    clear: both;
}
</style>
<body>
 Inspect the first block to see what I'm looking for
<!--**************************************************************************************-->
    <div class="siteWrapper">
        <section class="contentWrapper">
            <section class="productWrapper">
                <article class="promotionWrapper"></article>
                <article class="promotionWrapper"></article>
                <article class="promotionWrapper"></article>
                <article class="promotionWrapper"></article>
                <article class="promotionWrapper"></article>

                <div class="clearfloat"></div>
            </section>
        </section>

        <section class="contentWrapper">
            <section class="productWrapper">
                <article class="promotionWrapper"></article>
                <article class="promotionWrapper"></article>

                <div class="clearfloat"></div>
            </section>
        </section>
        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
<div class="result result0"></div>
        <div class="result result1"></div>
        <div class="result result2"></div>
        <div class="result result3"></div>
    </div>
<!--**************************************************************************************-->
</body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function PopulateTotalCounts()
{
var totalRows =0, totalArts =0, totalTop=-1;
$('.promotionWrapper').each(function(i,e){
      if(totalTop!=$(this).offset().top){
        totalTop = $(this).offset().top;
        totalRows++;
     } 
     totalArts++;
})
$(".result0").html("Total rows:"+totalRows+" and total articles:"+totalArts);
$(".result1").html("");
$(".result2").html("");
$(".result3").html("");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 PopulateTotalCounts();
 window.addEventListener("resize", PopulateTotalCounts);

 $('.promotionWrapper').click(function () {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $('.result2').html('Top = ' + offset.top);

    if($(this).prev().length == 0){
        $(".result3").html("There is no previous element");
    }
    else if($(this).prev().length > 0){
        var prevoff = $(this).prev().offset().top;
        $(".result3").html("the previous top is: " + prevoff);
    }

    $(".result1").html("Total number of articles in this section: " + $(this).parent().find('article.promotionWrapper').length);

    var rowCount =0;
    var top = -1;
    var artCount =1, artRowNumber=0;
    var freezArtCount=0;
    $(this).parent().find('article.promotionWrapper').each(function(i,e){
     if(top!=$(this).offset().top){
        top = $(this).offset().top;
        rowCount++; 
      if(freezArtCount==0) artCount =1;     
     }  
     if(freezArtCount==0){   
     if($(this).offset().top == offset.top && $(this).offset().left==offset.left)
     {
        freezArtCount=1;
        artRowNumber=rowCount;
     }
     else{ artCount++;}
     }
    });

    $(".result1").html($(".result1").html()+"<br/> Total number of rows in this section: " + rowCount);
    $(".result1").html($(".result1").html()+"<br/> Article is in Row:" + artRowNumber + " at Position:"+ artCount);
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

Update 1: For data-row attr for each article

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var rowCount1 =0;
    var top1 = -1;
    $('article.promotionWrapper').each(function(i,e){
     if(top1!=$(this).offset().top){
        top1 = $(this).offset().top;
        rowCount1++;            
     }  
     $(this).attr('data-row',rowCount1);    
        });
 PopulateTotalCounts();
```

Comment: Hi Mahesh.
Thanks for the response. This works quite nicely, but I need the articles(productionWrapper) to get an attribute which correlate with the row that its on.

Comment: Find update1 in my answer. It should do the needful.

Comment: Also please push this code to windows onresize event to handle attr updates on resize. Otherwise it would only add attributes only on load.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response again.
I haven't tried it out yet, but it looks like it should work.
I will comment again when I've tried it out.

Comment: I'm unable to get this work. I don't know if I'm making a total novice mistake in where I'm putting in the new code or not, but there's no new developments, I also seem unable to get a "console.log(rowCount1);".

Comment: It actually seems to be working somehow right now.
I'll look at it somemore and post back again tomorrow morning..

Thanks for all your help Mahesh.